# Why does asp.net perform a 302 before logging me in?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a default asp.net MVC project and it perfroms a 302[Found] redirect with my auth cookie and then I can see a request to the root for what seems to be no reason. I would have thought all that was needed was a single request but you can see from fiddler I have **two** which is confusing. Can anyone explain why the second request has to happen is this something I should disable?

[image]

Comment: By way of answering your question, ask yourself this: once you're logged in, do you still need to be at `/Account/Login` anymore?  Or would you be better off at `/`?

Comment: To put it another way, you get the 302 *after* you login, not *before.*

Comment: To set your cookie. It drops the cookie to the response, and issues a redirect to the browser.

Comment: Answer George! Answer thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for you to be logged in, ASP.NET needs to drop a cookie on your machine.  To do this, it must send the cookie in the response.  In order for that cookie to be used on subsequent requests, it must be sent on the following request.

A 302 redirect provides a nice way for this to happen.  The server issues the 302 redirect, sending the cookie to the browser along the way.  The browser responds by issuing another request to the redirected resource, which this time includes the cookie required to ensure the user is Authenticated.